# How to remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop?

Tags: apt

How do I remove gnome-ubuntu-desktop? As it doesnt work (not compatible with my virtual desktop as it requires xserver) I want to undo this installation. apt-get does only remove this package, and not the 1,3gb of apps installed. The autoremove does not work neither.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop and it's dependencies

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Purging your config/data

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```